PhpSpreadsheet put value of a repeated MYSQL record in a previously inserted EXCEL column
I edit the code since I managed to insert the MYSQL records into Excel, and put the data of DESCRIPCION and DIA (if tipoActividad=1) and NOMBRE_SESION and DIA (if tipoActividad=2) in their place (without repeating their entire range, but the problem is that I cannot resolve the issue that it finds a cell with repeated DNI and puts the current record in the next corresponding cell (for example: if previously AE(nombre_sesion) and AF(dia) were filled with a record, when finding the doc_identity corresponding to that row again, it should place it in cell AG(for nombre_sesion) and AH(dia).
First these are the columns where I want to place myself
columns Excel
here is the MYSQL table:
CREATE TABLE `detalle_reporte_mensual` (
  `id_detalle_reporte_mensual` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `id_reporte_mensual` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `id_paciente` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `planificacion_intervencion` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `tipo_intervencion` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `id_grupo_especifico` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `otros_relevantes` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_regimen` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `id_etapa` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `id_descripciones` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `dia_actividades` int(2) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '01-30',
  `id_sesiones` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `observaciones` text DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'TEMAS',
  `cambio_PPI` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;

I have made a modification to my PHP code today(04/11/2024) , let's see if anyone can help me out:
<?php
include("conexion.php"); // Asumiendo que tu conexión está configurada aquí
require __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";
$objCon = new Conexion();

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Coordinate;
use Monolog\Level;
use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;
use Monolog\Handler\FirePHPHandler;

// Configuración básica para mostrar todos los errores
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

//Guardando el tipo_actividad
// $tipoActividad=2;

class Registro
{
    public $interno;
 
    
    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->interno = [
            'doc_identidad' => $data['documento_identidad'],
            'datos_adicionales' => [
                'nombre_completo' => $data['apellidos_nombres_interno'],
                'fecha_ingreso' => $data['fecha_ingreso'],
                'fecha_nac' => $data['fecha_nacimiento'],
                'discapacidad' => $data['discapacidad'],
                'planificacion_intervencion' => $data['planificacion_intervencion'],
                'tipo_intervencion' => $data['tipo_intervencion'],
                'grupo_especifico' => $data['grupo_especifico'],
                'otros_relevantes' => $data['otros_relevantes'],
                'regimen' => $data['regimen'],
                'etapa' => $data['etapa'],
                'pabellon' => $data['pabellon'],
                'descripcion' => mb_convert_encoding($data['descripcion'], "UTF-8"),
                'dia' => $data['dia'],
                'nombre_sesion' => mb_convert_encoding($data['nombre_sesion'], "UTF-8"),
                'profesional' => $data['datos_profesional'],
                'observaciones' => $data['observaciones']
                // ... otros datos adicionales

            ]
        ];


    }
}

class GeneradorReporteExcel
{
    private $spreadsheet;
    private $sheet;
    private $logger;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
        $this->sheet = $this->spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

        //Logs
        $this->logger = new Logger('my_app');
        $this->logger->pushHandler(new StreamHandler(__DIR__ . '/reportes/debug.log', Level::Debug));
        // $this->logger->info('My logger is now ready');
        $this->logger->pushHandler(new FirePHPHandler());
    }

    private function obtenerValor($registro, $columna, $fila, $tipoActividad)
    {
        switch ($columna) {
            case 'C':
                return $registro->interno['doc_identidad'];
            case 'D':
                return $registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['nombre_completo'];
            case 'E':
                return 'MASCULINO';
            case 'F':
                return $registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['fecha_ingreso'];
            case 'G':
                return $registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['fecha_nac'];
            case 'H':
                // Obtener la celda de fecha de nacimiento (suponiendo que 'G2' es relativa)
                $celdaFechaNacimiento = 'G' . $fila; // Ajusta la fila según tu lógica
                // Construir la fórmula completa
                $formula = "=(NOW()-" . $celdaFechaNacimiento . ")/365-0.5";
                return $formula;
            case 'I':
                return $registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['discapacidad'];
            case 'J':
                //planificacion d ela intervencion
                if ($registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['planificacion_intervencion'] == 1) {
                    $planificacion_intervencion = "PTI_EN_PROCESO";
                }

                if ($registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['planificacion_intervencion'] == 2) {
                    $planificacion_intervencion = "PTI_P";
                }

                if ($registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['planificacion_intervencion'] == 3) {
                    $planificacion_intervencion = "PTI_S";
                }
                if ($registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['planificacion_intervencion'] == 4) {
                    $planificacion_intervencion = "POPE_ANTIGUA";
                }
                return $planificacion_intervencion;
            case 'K':
                //tipo de intervencion
                if ($registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['tipo_intervencion'] == 1) {
                    $tipo_intervencion = "INDUCCION_Y_ADAPTACION_AL_REGIMEN_PENITENCIARIO";
                }
                if ($registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['tipo_intervencion'] == 2) {
                    $tipo_intervencion = "INTERVENCION_GENERAL";
                }
                if ($registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['tipo_intervencion'] == 3) {
                    $tipo_intervencion = "INTERVENCION_ESPECIALIZADA";
                }
                if ($registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['tipo_intervencion'] == 4) {
                    $tipo_intervencion = "PROGRAMACIÓN_SOBRE_NECESIDADES_DE_INTERVENCIÓN_COMPLEMENTARIA";
                }
                return $tipo_intervencion;
            case 'L':
                return $registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['grupo_especifico'];
            case 'M':
                return $registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['otros_relevantes'];
            case 'N':
                return $registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['regimen'];
            case 'O':
                return $registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['etapa'];
            case 'P':
                return $registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['pabellon'];
            case 'Q':
            case 'S':
            case 'U':
            case 'W':
            case 'Y':
            case 'AA':
            case 'AC':
                if ($tipoActividad === 1) {
                    $descripcion=$registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['descripcion']; // O el campo de descripción que corresponda
                } else {
                    $descripcion='';
                }
                return $descripcion;
            case 'R':
            case 'T':
            case 'V':
            case 'X':
            case 'Z':
            case 'AB':
            case 'AD':
                if ($tipoActividad === 1) {
                    $dia=$registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['dia']; // O el campo de descripción que corresponda
                } else {
                    $dia='';
                }
                return $dia;
            case 'AE':
            case 'AG':
            case 'AI':
            case 'AK':
            case 'AM':
                if ($tipoActividad == 2) {
                    // Manejar el caso cuando tipoActividad es 2 (si aplica)
                    $nombre_sesion=$registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['nombre_sesion']; // O el campo de nombre de sesión que corresponda
                } else {
                    $nombre_sesion='';
                }
                return $nombre_sesion;

            case 'AF':
            case 'AH':
            case 'AJ':
            case 'AL':
            case 'AN':
                if ($tipoActividad == 2) {
                    // Manejar el caso cuando tipoActividad no es 1 ni 2
                    $dia=$registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['dia']; // O el campo de nombre de sesión que corresponda
                } else {
                    $dia='';
                }
                return $dia;

            case 'AO':
                return $registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['profesional'];
            case 'AP':
                return $registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['observaciones'];
                // case 'AQ':
                //     return $registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['nombre_completo'];
            default:
                return '';
        }
    }



    private function escribirEnCelda($columna, $fila, $valor)
    {
        // $this->logger->debug("Escribiendo $valor en la celda $columna$fila");
        // $this->sheet->setCellValue($columna . $fila, $valor);

        try {
            // $this->logger->info('My logger is now ready');
            // $this->logger->debug("Escribiendo $valor en la celda $columna$fila");
            $this->sheet->setCellValue($columna . $fila, $valor);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->error("Error al escribir en la celda: " . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    private function getRangoColumnas($tipoActividad, $esNuevoRegistro)
    {
        if($tipoActividad==1){
        return $esNuevoRegistro ? ['C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'AA', 'AB', 'AC', 'AD','AO','AP'] : ['O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'AA', 'AB', 'AC', 'AD'];
        }else{
            return $esNuevoRegistro ?  ['C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'AE', 'AF', 'AG', 'AH','AI','AJ','AK','AL','AM','AN','AO','AP'] : ['AE', 'AF', 'AG', 'AH','AI','AJ','AK','AL','AM','AN'];
        }
    }

    private function buscarFilaPorDni($dni)
    {
        // Suponiendo que el DNI está en la columna C
        $highestRow = $this->sheet->getHighestRow();
        $this->logger->debug("Cuantas filas hay?: $highestRow");
        for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; $row++) {
            
            if ($this->sheet->getCell('C' . $row)->getValue() === $dni) {
                // $this->logger->debug("Fila del archivo Excel: $this->sheet->getCell('C' . $row)->getValue() == DNI: $dni");
                $tipoActividad = 2; //$this->sheet->getCell('A' . $row)->getValue(); // Suponiendo que el tipo de actividad está en la columna A
                $rangoColumnas = $this->getRangoColumnas($tipoActividad, false);
                return [
                    'fila' => $row,
                    'rangoColumnas' => $rangoColumnas
                ];
            }
            // $this->logger->debug("DNI EXCEL: $this->sheet->getCell('C' . $row)->getValue()  NO ES IGUAL A DNI SQL: $dni");
            
        }
       
        return false;
     
    }

 private function crearNuevaFila($fila, $registro, $rangoColumnas, $tipoActividad,$esNuevoRegistro) {
    $columnaIndex = 0; // Inicializamos el índice de columna

    foreach ($rangoColumnas as $columna) {
        if($tipoActividad=2 && $esNuevoRegistro==true){
            if($columnaIndex==16 || $columnaIndex==17 || $columnaIndex==18 || $columnaIndex==19 || $columnaIndex==20 || $columnaIndex==21 || $columnaIndex==22){
                // $this->logger->debug("columnaIndex: $columnaIndex - Pertenece a la columna: $columna ---> NO SE REGISTRO");
                continue;
            }
        }else{

            $valor = $this->obtenerValor($registro, $columna, $fila, $tipoActividad);
            $this->escribirEnCelda($columna, $fila, $valor);
            // $this->logger->debug("columnaIndex: $columnaIndex - Pertenece a la columna: $columna ---> valor = $valor ");
            $columnaIndex++;
       }
        
      
        
        // $this->logger->debug("columnaIndex: $columnaIndex - Pertenece a la columna: $columna[$columnaIndex] ---> valor = $valor ");
        // Validación adicional: Verificar si el valor es una cadena vacía o null
        // if (!empty($valor)) {
        //     $this->escribirEnCelda($columna, $fila, $valor);
        //     $columnaIndex++; // Incrementamos el índice solo si escribimos un valor
             
        //     // Si es un nuevo registro y ya escribimos los dos primeros valores, salimos del bucle
        // for($columnaIndex=15;$columnaIndex<24;$columnaIndex++) {
        //         continue 2;
        //     }
        //     // $columnaIndex = 23; // Ajustar el índice para la siguiente columna (AG)
        // }
    }
}
 

    private function actualizarFila($fila, $registro,  $rangosAdicionales=true)
    {
        $tipoActividad = 2; //$registro->tipo_actividad;
        $rangoColumnas = $this->getRangoColumnas($tipoActividad, false);

        // Encontrar la primera columna vacía en el rango adicional
        $columnaVacía = null;
        foreach ($rangosAdicionales[$tipoActividad] as $columna) {
            if ($this->sheet->getCell($columna . $fila)->getValue() === null) {
                $columnaVacía = $columna;
                break;
            }
        }

        // Si se encontró una columna vacía, escribir el valor
        if ($columnaVacía) {
            $columnaIndex = array_search($columnaVacía, $rangoColumnas);
            $valor = $registro->datos_adicionales[$columnaIndex]; // $this->obtenerValor($registro, $columna);
            $this->escribirEnCelda($columnaVacía, $fila, $valor);
        }
    }



    public function generarReporte($registros, $rutaArchivo, $formatoArchivo)
    {
        // Cargar el archivo de formato
        $this->spreadsheet = IOFactory::load($formatoArchivo);
        $this->sheet = $this->spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

        $fila = 2;

        foreach ($registros as $registro) {
            $tipoActividad = 2; //$registro->datos_adicionales['tipo_intervencion'];

            // Determinar si es un nuevo registro o no ---> OK!
            if ($this->buscarFilaPorDni($registro->interno['doc_identidad'])) {
                $rangoColumnas = $this->getRangoColumnas($tipoActividad, false); // Registro existente
            } else {
                $rangoColumnas = $this->getRangoColumnas($tipoActividad, true); // Nuevo registro
            }


            $dni = $registro->interno['doc_identidad'];
            $filaExistente = $this->buscarFilaPorDni($dni);

            if ($filaExistente) {
                // $this->logger->info('My logger is now ready');
                $this->actualizarFila($filaExistente, $registro, $rangoColumnas);
            } else {
                $this->crearNuevaFila($fila, $registro, $rangoColumnas, $tipoActividad,true);
                $fila++;
            }
        }

        // Guardar el archivo Excel
        $writer = IOFactory::createWriter($this->spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
        $writer->save($rutaArchivo);
        return "Archivo Generado con Exito!";
    }

    // ... (resto de los métodos)
}

// ... (tu código de conexión a la base de datos y consulta SQL)
$id_reporte = 1;
// Consulta SQL
$sql = "SELECT I.doc_identidad AS 'DOCUMENTO_IDENTIDAD',
                            I.ape_nombres AS 'APELLIDOS_NOMBRES_INTERNO',
                            I.fecha_ingreso AS 'FECHA_INGRESO',
                            I.fecha_nacimiento AS 'FECHA_NACIMIENTO',
                            I.discapacidad AS 'discapacidad',

                            DET.planificacion_intervencion AS 'PLANIFICACION_INTERVENCION',
                            DET.tipo_intervencion AS 'TIPO_INTERVENCION',
                            GRUP.nombre_grupo_especifico AS 'GRUPO_ESPECIFICO',
                            DET.otros_relevantes AS 'OTROS_RELEVANTES',
                            REG.nombre_regimen AS 'REGIMEN',
                            ETP.nombre_etapa AS 'ETAPA',
                            I.pab_celda_etapa AS 'PABELLON',
                            DESCRIP.nombre_descripciones AS 'DESCRIPCION',
                            DET.dia_actividades AS 'dia',
                            SES.nombre_sesiones AS 'nombre_sesion',
                            CONCAT(U.ape_paterno,' ',U.ape_materno,' ',U.nombres) AS 'DATOS_PROFESIONAL',
                            DET.observaciones AS 'OBSERVACIONES',
                            DET.cambio_PTIP_PTIS AS 'PTI_P_PTI_S'
                        FROM reportes_mensuales REP
                        INNER JOIN detalle_reporte_mensual DET ON REP.id_reporte_mensual=DET.id_reporte_mensual
                        INNER JOIN grupo_especifico GRUP ON DET.id_grupo_especifico=GRUP.id_grupo_especifico
                        INNER JOIN internos I ON DET.id_interno=I.id_interno
                        INNER JOIN usuarios U ON REP.id_usuario=U.id_usuario
                        INNER JOIN regimen REG ON DET.id_regimen=REG.id_regimen
                        INNER JOIN etapa ETP ON DET.id_etapa=ETP.id_etapa
                        INNER JOIN descripciones DESCRIP ON DET.id_descripciones=DESCRIP.id_descripciones
                        INNER JOIN sessiones SES ON DET.id_sesiones=SES.id_sesiones

                        WHERE REP.id_reporte_mensual=:id_reporte"; // Tu consulta SQL completa

$rsDetalleReporte = $objCon->getConexion()->prepare($sql);
$rsDetalleReporte->bindParam(':id_reporte', $id_reporte, PDO::PARAM_INT);

if ($rsDetalleReporte->execute()) {
    $registros = [];
    while ($row = $rsDetalleReporte->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $registro = new Registro($row);
        $registros[] = $registro;
        // Imprimir los datos del registro para verificar
        // echo json_encode($registro)."<br>";
    }

    // Verificar si el array $registros está vacío
    if (empty($registros)) {
        echo "No se encontraron registros.";
    } else {
        // Generar el reporte
        $generador = new GeneradorReporteExcel();
        $generador->generarReporte($registros, 'reportes/reporte_actualizado.xlsx', 'reportes/FORMATO_SOCIAL.xlsx');
    }
} else {
    // Manejar errores en la ejecución de la consulta
    echo "Error al ejecutar la consulta: " . $rsDetalleReporte->errorInfo()[2];
}
?>

responses are appreciated!

Is this a mysql question (you struggle with extracting data out of mysql) or is tgis a php problem (data extracted from mysql is fine, but you struggle to pit the data at the right place in phpexcel)?

Hi @Shadow ,, the problem I have is filling in the data of the repeated records in the corresponding row in Excel, I locate the row in Excel but I don't know why the new data is not saved in the following columns.

Do you really have a GOTO in that code. Naughty

Hi RiggsFolly, I couldn't think of anything else apart from the break that has already been commented, I accept suggestions to improve the code.  ^_^

I have made a modification to my PHP code, let's see if anyone can help me out:, Now I create 2 arrays and store in $arrayDnisRepetados the repeated values ​​of the SQL query and in $arrayDnisExcel I store the values ​​read from Excel. Can anyone help me or tell me what I'm doing wrong? I've already removed the GOTO (bad practice)

Please reduce the lines of code. Optimize your question to provide a [mcve]. It's easier to help you with your problem if we don't have to sift through 416 lines of php to do it.

I have shortened the code so that only the identity document (identity_doc), Full Name (full_name), and the cells that should be affected by Activity Type (activity_type) are processed. The idea is the same, I could not remove more code because there is the SQL query (which I already removed the data from) and other logic.

Problem solved,. For those who may have a similar problem I am sharing the code
    <?php
include("conexion.php"); // Asumiendo que tu conexión está configurada aquí
require __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";
$objCon = new Conexion();

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Coordinate;
use Monolog\Level;
use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;
use Monolog\Handler\FirePHPHandler;

// Configuración básica para mostrar todos los errores
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

//Guardando el tipo_actividad e id_reporte
$tipo_Actividad=$_POST['tipo_actividad'];
$id_reporte = $_POST['id_reporte'];

class Registro
{
    public $interno;
    
    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->interno = [
            'doc_identidad' => $data['documento_identidad'],
            'datos_adicionales' => [
                'nombre_completo' => $data['apellidos_nombres_interno'],
                'fecha_ingreso' => $data['fecha_ingreso'],
                'fecha_nac' => $data['fecha_nacimiento'],
                'discapacidad' => $data['discapacidad'],
                'planificacion_intervencion' => $data['planificacion_intervencion'],
                'tipo_intervencion' => $data['tipo_intervencion'],
                'grupo_especifico' => $data['grupo_especifico'],
                'otros_relevantes' => $data['otros_relevantes'],
                'regimen' => $data['regimen'],
                'etapa' => $data['etapa'],
                'pabellon' => $data['pabellon'],
                'descripcion' => mb_convert_encoding($data['descripcion'], "UTF-8"),
                'dia' => $data['dia'],
                'nombre_sesion' => mb_convert_encoding($data['nombre_sesion'], "UTF-8"),
                'profesional' => $data['datos_profesional'],
                'observaciones' => $data['observaciones']
                // ... otros datos adicionales

            ]
        ];
        // $this->nombre_completo = $data['apellidos_nombres_interno'];



    }
}

class GeneradorReporteExcel
{
    private $spreadsheet;
    private $sheet;
    private $logger;
    

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
        $this->sheet = $this->spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

        //Logs
        $this->logger = new Logger('my_app');
        $this->logger->pushHandler(new StreamHandler(__DIR__ . '/reportes/debug.log', Level::Debug));
        // $this->logger->info('My logger is now ready');
        $this->logger->pushHandler(new FirePHPHandler());
    }

    private function obtenerValor($registro, $columna, $fila, $tipoActividad)
    {
        switch ($columna) {
            case 'C':
                return $registro->interno['doc_identidad'];
            case 'D':
                return $registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['nombre_completo'];
            case 'E':
                return 'MASCULINO';
            case 'F':
                return $registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['fecha_ingreso'];
            case 'G':
                return $registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['fecha_nac'];
            case 'H':
                // Obtener la celda de fecha de nacimiento (suponiendo que 'G2' es relativa)
                $celdaFechaNacimiento = 'G' . $fila; // Ajusta la fila según tu lógica
                // Construir la fórmula completa
                $formula = "=(NOW()-" . $celdaFechaNacimiento . ")/365-0.5";
                return $formula;
            case 'I':
                return $registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['discapacidad'];
            case 'J':
                //planificacion d ela intervencion
                if ($registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['planificacion_intervencion'] == 1) {
                    $planificacion_intervencion = "PTI_EN_PROCESO";
                }

                if ($registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['planificacion_intervencion'] == 2) {
                    $planificacion_intervencion = "PTI_P";
                }

                if ($registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['planificacion_intervencion'] == 3) {
                    $planificacion_intervencion = "PTI_S";
                }
                if ($registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['planificacion_intervencion'] == 4) {
                    $planificacion_intervencion = "POPE_ANTIGUA";
                }
                return $planificacion_intervencion;
            case 'K':
                //tipo de intervencion
                if ($registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['tipo_intervencion'] == 1) {
                    $tipo_intervencion = "INDUCCION_Y_ADAPTACION_AL_REGIMEN_PENITENCIARIO";
                }
                if ($registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['tipo_intervencion'] == 2) {
                    $tipo_intervencion = "INTERVENCION_GENERAL";
                }
                if ($registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['tipo_intervencion'] == 3) {
                    $tipo_intervencion = "INTERVENCION_ESPECIALIZADA";
                }
                if ($registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['tipo_intervencion'] == 4) {
                    $tipo_intervencion = "PROGRAMACIÓN_SOBRE_NECESIDADES_DE_INTERVENCIÓN_COMPLEMENTARIA";
                }
                return $tipo_intervencion;
            case 'L':
                return $registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['grupo_especifico'];
            case 'M':
                return $registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['otros_relevantes'];
            case 'N':
                return $registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['regimen'];
            case 'O':
                return $registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['etapa'];
            case 'P':
                return $registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['pabellon'];
            case 'Q':
            case 'S':
            case 'U':
            case 'W':
            case 'Y':
            case 'AA':
            case 'AC':
                if ($tipoActividad === 1) {
                    $descripcion=$registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['descripcion']; // O el campo de descripción que corresponda
                } else {
                    $descripcion='';
                }
                return $descripcion;
            case 'R':
            case 'T':
            case 'V':
            case 'X':
            case 'Z':
            case 'AB':
            case 'AD':
                if ($tipoActividad === 1) {
                    $dia=$registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['dia']; // O el campo de descripción que corresponda
                } else {
                    $dia='';
                }
                return $dia;
            case 'AE':
            case 'AG':
            case 'AI':
            case 'AK':
            case 'AM':
                if ($tipoActividad == 2) {
                    // Manejar el caso cuando tipoActividad es 2 (si aplica)
                    $nombre_sesion=$registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['nombre_sesion']; // O el campo de nombre de sesión que corresponda
                } else {
                    $nombre_sesion='';
                }
                return $nombre_sesion;

            case 'AF':
            case 'AH':
            case 'AJ':
            case 'AL':
            case 'AN':
                if ($tipoActividad == 2) {
                    // Manejar el caso cuando tipoActividad no es 1 ni 2
                    $dia=$registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['dia']; // O el campo de nombre de sesión que corresponda
                } else {
                    $dia='';
                }
                return $dia;

            case 'AO':
                return $registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['profesional'];
            case 'AP':
                return $registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['observaciones'];
                // case 'AQ':
                //     return $registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['nombre_completo'];
            default:
                return '';
        }
    }



    private function escribirEnCelda($columna, $fila, $valor)
    {
        // $this->logger->debug("Escribiendo $valor en la celda $columna$fila");
        // $this->sheet->setCellValue($columna . $fila, $valor);

        try {
            // $this->logger->info('My logger is now ready');
            // $this->logger->debug("Escribiendo $valor en la celda $columna$fila");
            $this->sheet->setCellValue($columna . $fila, $valor);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->error("Error al escribir en la celda: " . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    private function getRangoColumnas($tipoActividad, $esNuevoRegistro)
    {
        if($tipoActividad==1){
        return $esNuevoRegistro ? ['C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'AA', 'AB', 'AC', 'AD'] : ['O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'AA', 'AB', 'AC', 'AD'];
        }else{
            return $esNuevoRegistro ?  ['C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'AE', 'AF', 'AG', 'AH','AI','AJ','AK','AL','AM','AN','AO','AP'] : ['AE', 'AF', 'AG', 'AH','AI','AJ','AK','AL','AM','AN'];
        }
    }

    private function buscarFilaPorDni($dni)
    {
        // Suponiendo que el DNI está en la columna C
        $highestRow = $this->sheet->getHighestRow();
        // $this->logger->debug("Cuantas filas hay?: $highestRow");
        for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; $row++) {
            
            if ($this->sheet->getCell('C' . $row)->getValue() == $dni) {
                // $this->logger->debug("Fila del archivo Excel: $this->sheet->getCell('C' . $row)->getValue() == DNI: $dni");
                $tipoActividad = 2; //$this->sheet->getCell('A' . $row)->getValue(); // Suponiendo que el tipo de actividad está en la columna A
                $rangoColumnas = $this->getRangoColumnas($tipoActividad, false);
                return [
                    'fila' => $row,
                    'rangoColumnas' => $rangoColumnas
                ];
            }
            // $this->logger->debug("DNI EXCEL: $this->sheet->getCell('C' . $row)->getValue()  NO ES IGUAL A DNI SQL: $dni");
            
        }
       
        return false;
     
    }

 private function crearNuevaFila($fila, $registro, $rangoColumnas, $tipoActividad,$esNuevoRegistro) {
    $columnaIndex = 0; // Inicializamos el índice de columna

    foreach ($rangoColumnas as $columna) {
        if($tipoActividad=2 && $esNuevoRegistro==true){
            if($columnaIndex==16 || $columnaIndex==17 || $columnaIndex==18 || $columnaIndex==19 || $columnaIndex==20 || $columnaIndex==21 || $columnaIndex==22){
                // $this->logger->debug("columnaIndex: $columnaIndex - Pertenece a la columna: $columna ---> NO SE REGISTRO");
                continue;
            }
        }else{

       }
        
        $valor = $this->obtenerValor($registro, $columna, $fila, $tipoActividad);
        $this->escribirEnCelda($columna, $fila, $valor);
        // $this->logger->debug("columnaIndex: $columnaIndex - Pertenece a la columna: $columna ---> valor = $valor ");
        $columnaIndex++;
    }
}
 

    private function actualizarFila($fila, $registro,  $rangosAdicionales)
    {
        $tipoActividad = 2; //$registro->tipo_actividad;

        // Encontrar la primera columna vacía en el rango adicional
         $columnaVacia = null;

    //    $this->logger->debug("Rango: $rangosAdicionales[$tipoActividad]");
         foreach ($rangosAdicionales as $columna) {

             if ($this->sheet->getCell( $columna. $fila)->getValue() === null) {
                 $columnaVacia =  $columna;
                //  $this->logger->debug("Columna Vacia: $columnaVacia");
                 break;
             }
          }

        // Si se encontró una columna vacía, escribir el valor
         if ($columnaVacia) {
            //  $columnaIndex = array_search($columnaVacia, $rangosAdicionales);
            //  $this->logger->debug("ColumnaIndex: $columnaIndex ");
            $sesion =$registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['nombre_sesion']; // $this->obtenerValor($registro, $columna);
            $this->escribirEnCelda($columnaVacia, $fila, $sesion);
            //aumentando en 1 para el día
            $columnaVacia++;
            $dia=$registro->interno['datos_adicionales']['dia'];
            $this->escribirEnCelda($columnaVacia, $fila, $dia);
         }
    }



    public function generarReporte($registros, $rutaArchivo, $formatoArchivo,$tipoActividad)
    {
        // Cargar el archivo de formato
        $this->spreadsheet = IOFactory::load($formatoArchivo);
        $this->sheet = $this->spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

        $fila = 2;

        foreach ($registros as $registro) {
            $tipoActividad = $tipoActividad; //$registro->datos_adicionales['tipo_intervencion'];

            // Determinar si es un nuevo registro o no ---> OK!
            if ($this->buscarFilaPorDni($registro->interno['doc_identidad'])) {
                $rangoColumnas = $this->getRangoColumnas($tipoActividad, false); // Registro existente
                //hayando la fila repetida
                // $dni = $registro->interno['doc_identidad'];
                 $resultadoBusqueda=$this->buscarFilaPorDni($registro->interno['doc_identidad'])['fila'];
                    //  $this->logger->debug("FILA REPETIDA: ".$resultadoBusqueda);
                // if (is_array($resultadoBusqueda)) {
                //     $filaExistente =  $resultadoBusqueda[0];//$this->buscarFilaPorDni($dni)[0];
                //     $this->logger->debug("FILA REPETIDA: $filaExistente");
                // }
                $this->actualizarFila($resultadoBusqueda, $registro, $rangoColumnas);
                //  $this->logger->debug("BuscarFilaDNI devuelve estos valores: ".json_encode($this->buscarFilaPorDni($registro->interno['doc_identidad'])));
            } else {
                $rangoColumnas = $this->getRangoColumnas($tipoActividad, true); // Nuevo registro
                $this->crearNuevaFila($fila, $registro, $rangoColumnas, $tipoActividad,true);
                $fila++;
                // $this->logger->debug("BuscarFilaDNI devuelve estos valores: ".$this->buscarFilaPorDni($registro->interno['doc_identidad']));
            }
        }

        // Guardar el archivo Excel
        $writer = IOFactory::createWriter($this->spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
        $writer->save($rutaArchivo);
    }

}


// Consulta SQL
$sql = "SELECT I.doc_identidad AS 'DOCUMENTO_IDENTIDAD',
                            I.ape_nombres AS 'APELLIDOS_NOMBRES_INTERNO',
                            I.fecha_ingreso AS 'FECHA_INGRESO',
                            I.fecha_nacimiento AS 'FECHA_NACIMIENTO',
                            I.discapacidad AS 'discapacidad',

                            DET.planificacion_intervencion AS 'PLANIFICACION_INTERVENCION',
                            DET.tipo_intervencion AS 'TIPO_INTERVENCION',
                            GRUP.nombre_grupo_especifico AS 'GRUPO_ESPECIFICO',
                            DET.otros_relevantes AS 'OTROS_RELEVANTES',
                            REG.nombre_regimen AS 'REGIMEN',
                            ETP.nombre_etapa AS 'ETAPA',
                            I.pab_celda_etapa AS 'PABELLON',
                            DESCRIP.nombre_descripciones AS 'DESCRIPCION',
                            DET.dia_actividades AS 'dia',
                            SES.nombre_sesiones AS 'nombre_sesion',
                            CONCAT(U.ape_paterno,' ',U.ape_materno,' ',U.nombres) AS 'DATOS_PROFESIONAL',
                            DET.observaciones AS 'OBSERVACIONES',
                            DET.cambio_PTIP_PTIS AS 'PTI_P_PTI_S'
                        FROM reportes_mensuales REP
                        INNER JOIN detalle_reporte_mensual DET ON REP.id_reporte_mensual=DET.id_reporte_mensual
                        INNER JOIN grupo_especifico GRUP ON DET.id_grupo_especifico=GRUP.id_grupo_especifico
                        INNER JOIN internos I ON DET.id_interno=I.id_interno
                        INNER JOIN usuarios U ON REP.id_usuario=U.id_usuario
                        INNER JOIN regimen REG ON DET.id_regimen=REG.id_regimen
                        INNER JOIN etapa ETP ON DET.id_etapa=ETP.id_etapa
                        INNER JOIN descripciones DESCRIP ON DET.id_descripciones=DESCRIP.id_descripciones
                        INNER JOIN sessiones SES ON DET.id_sesiones=SES.id_sesiones

                        WHERE REP.id_reporte_mensual=:id_reporte"; // Tu consulta SQL completa

$rsDetalleReporte = $objCon->getConexion()->prepare($sql);
$rsDetalleReporte->bindParam(':id_reporte', $id_reporte, PDO::PARAM_INT);

if ($rsDetalleReporte->execute()) {
    $registros = [];
    while ($row = $rsDetalleReporte->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $registro = new Registro($row);
        $registros[] = $registro;

        // Imprimir los datos del registro para verificar
        // echo json_encode($registro)."<br>";
    }

    // Verificar si el array $registros está vacío
    if (empty($registros)) {
        echo "No se encontraron registros.";
    } else {
        // Generar el reporte
        $generador = new GeneradorReporteExcel();
        $generador->generarReporte($registros, 'reportes/reporte_actualizado.xlsx', 'reportes/FORMATO_SOCIAL.xlsx',$tipo_Actividad);
    }
} else {
    // Manejar errores en la ejecución de la consulta
    echo "Error al ejecutar la consulta: " . $rsDetalleReporte->errorInfo()[2];
}
?>


Hi, please explain how this can address the question. There is only code here...  Be sure to read how to answer. Thank you
